# How to use cloudformation to create an IAM user/role

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to create an access key in IAM-User, but I don't have permission to do that, so I want to use cloudformation to create an IAM user/role which I have permission, can anyone shows me a template for that? I couldn't find a correct one, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have permission to do that

If you don't have permissions to create IAM users/roles you **can't create them with CloudFormation** either as it uses your permissions, which you lack, to create resources.

The only way would be if you were given a role which can be assumed by CloudFormation to create IAM entities, instead of using your permissions. But this is unlikely. You can ask your AWS admins if they can create/give you such a role for CloudFormation.